# NewWindow3 Event Not Fired

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, new-window

I'm trying to use the `NewWindow3` event with the Microsoft Web Browser control so that I can capture the URL and prevent it from opening Internet Explorer. `NewWindow2` fires fine, but `NewWindow3` does not. The only relevent thing I can find is [NewWindow3 event on extended WebBrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914922/newwindow3-event-on-extended-webbrowser), but I don't want to use a custom control. I want to use the stock control. What can I do to get the `NewWindow3` event to work without using a custom control?

```
private void Form1_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    webBrowser1.Navigate("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
    SHDocVw.WebBrowser browser = (SHDocVw.WebBrowser)webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance;
    Debug.Assert(browser != null);
    browser.NewWindow2 += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2EventHandler(browser_NewWindow2);
    browser.NewWindow3 += new SHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3EventHandler(browser_NewWindow3);
}

void browser_NewWindow2( ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel )
{
    Debug.Write("NewWindow2");
}

private void browser_NewWindow3( ref object ppDisp, ref bool Cancel, uint dwFlags, string bstrUrlContext, string bstrUrl )
{
    Debug.Write(bstrUrl);
}
```

Comment: What happens if you subscribe to the events before you call `Navigate()`? What happens if you _only_ subscribe to `NewWindow3`?

Comment: @PeterDuniho, `webBrowser1.ActiveXInstance` returns null and I cannot subscribe to the event.

Comment: @HansPassant, I agree that it shouldn't but it does.

Comment: @HansPassant. [https://youtu.be/D9wcGMLogaA](https://youtu.be/D9wcGMLogaA)

Answer (score 2):

After weeks of trying to figure this out, I finally figured it out. Rather than using the .Net wrapper of the Web Browser control, I added the Web Browser Control as an ActiveX COM control by doing the following:

- Right click on any control in the *Toolbox*, and select *Choose Items...*
- Go to *COM Components* tab and select **Microsoft Web Browser**
- From the *All Windows Forms* category of the *Toolbox*, add a **Microsoft Web Browser** control to the form.
- The `NewWindow3` event is exposed normally. No need to use `webBrowser1.AxtiveXControl` to get to it.
- Add code for `NewWindow3` event

  ```
  private void axWebBrowser1_NewWindow3( object sender, AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3Event e )
  {
      Debug.WriteLine(e.bstrUrl);
      e.cancel = true;
  }
  ```

Comment: You still can use the .NET `WeBrowser` control like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20902928/1768303).

Comment: @Noseratio, Thanks, but that seems rather over complicated compared to just using the native COM control.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
    // Form_Load
this.axWebBrowser1.NewWindow3 += new AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3EventHandler(this.axWebBrowser1_NewWindow3);
this.axWebBrowser1.NewWindow2 += new AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2EventHandler(this.axWebBrowser1_NewWindow2);

object obj = null; 


private void axWebBrowser1_NewWindow2(object sender, AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow2Event e)
{
      e.cancel = true;
}

private void axWebBrowser1_NewWindow3(object sender, AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_NewWindow3Event e)
{
      //MessageBox.Show(e.bstrUrl);
      Form1 nF = new Form1();
      nF.axWebBrowser1.RegisterAsBrowser = true;
      e.ppDisp = nF.axWebBrowser1.Application;
      nF.Visible = true;
      nF.axWebBrowser1.Navigate(e.bstrUrl, ref obj, ref obj, ref obj, ref obj);
      e.cancel = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As explained in this [post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8c43c6f5-4e9f-4491-8219-1b0eeb7b225b/wpf-webbrowser-control-on-x64-machines-launches-new-ie-window-instead-of-staying-inside-of-control?forum=wpf),
try to set the properties `Embed Interop Type` of the reference `SHDocVw` to `false`.